# (C++) Como fazer um programa escrever em 2 arquivos diferentes?

Tags: c++, arquivo

Fiz 2 tentativas, a primeira dá erro, e a segunda não escreve. poderiam me ajudar?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string linha;
    fstream fin ("ex2.txt");
    ofstream fout("ex2par.txt");
    ofstream fout("ex2impar.txt");
    if(fin.is_open())
    {
        while(getline(fin,linha))
        {
            int num = atoi(linha.c_str());
            if (num%2 == 0)
            {
                cout << "par " << num << endl;
                fout.open("ex2par.txt",ios::app);
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "impar " << num << endl;
                fout.open("ex2impar.txt",ios::app);
            }

        }
    }
}
/*int main()
{
    string linha;
    fstream fin("ex2.txt");
    ofstream par("ex2par.txt");
    ofstream impar("ex2impar.txt");
    if(fin.is_open())
    {
        while(getline(fin,linha))
        {
            int num = atoi(linha.c_str());
            if (num%2 == 0)
            {

                cout << "par " << num << endl;
                par.open("ex2par.txt");
            }
            else
            {

               cout << "impar " << num << endl;
                impar.open("ex2par.txt");
            }
        }

    }
}*/
```

Comment: Mas as mensagens você está enviando todas para o `cout`. Em que momento você realmente tentou escrever os textos nós arquivos?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, no caso não seria na declarada do  ofstream par("ex2par.txt");
    e do ofstream impar("ex2impar.txt");, pois tentei os dois com FOUT mas deu erro, como na parte comentada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite.

Sobre a parte não comentada:

você criou 2 variáveis com o mesmo nome fout. Se vc. chamar a segunda de fout2 por exemplo não vai dar erro.
Quando vc. inicializa os streams com os nomes dos arquivos eles já vão se abrir. Pode tirar os comandos open.
Para escrever para os arquivos utilize as variáveis dos streams correspondentes e não cout. Por exemplo: fout << "par" << endl;
Veja se o código a seguir te ajuda:

```c
int main()

{

    string linha;

    fstream fin ("ex2.txt");

    ofstream fout("ex2par.txt");

    ofstream fout2("ex2impar.txt");

    if(fin.is_open())

    {
        while(getline(fin,linha))

        {

            int num = atoi(linha.c_str());

            if (num%2 == 0)

            {

                fout << "par " << num << endl;

            }

            else

            {

                fout2 << "impar " << num << endl;

            }


        }

    }

}
```